# How to autorun .sh

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, autostart

I have a game server that I would like to manage restarts automatically

Currently I am doing this to run the server

```
screen -dmS screenname // create a new screen
screen -xs screenname // attatch to screen
bash ~/start.sh
```

Every few hours this program will crash and I'll have to SSH in to run this manually.

Is there a way I can possibly have .sh auto boot if it detects it goes down?

Comment: Have you looked into `monit`? See https://mmonit.com/monit/#home.

Comment: create a systemd service ? do you have root access?

Answer (score 0):

There are Some server crash file(mean if server crash this file will be  execute)

CREATE your bash file

Or place command in that file(script)

`whenever crash happen, your file automatically Run`

---

**OR**

Next **start up**(whenever a OS start it run some applications that mention in startup for os like:*start wifi something like that*)

```bsh
$ cd ~ #home dir
$ touch AutoRun.sh   #Create AutoRun.sh file
$ nano AutoRun.sh /vim AutoRun.sh
      #paste Your Command there here
      screen -dmS screenname // create a new screen
      screen -xs screenname // attatch to screen
      bash ~/start.sh
$ crontab -e
  # Adding a line like this to it:
  @reboot ~/AutoRun.sh
  #### ⬇️⬇️⬇️ for reference about ⬇️⬇️⬇️
```

Follow up this link :::: [Click me](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/1597109)